# Why the 'FileNotFoundError' when the error specifically names a file when I have only given it a directory

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, iteration

I am attempting to use a for-loop to iterate over csv files in a directory, processing them with a pre-defined function.

```
# Define a function to collect form page data and save as a new csv file
def writeFormPage(file, path):
    '''
    Input:
        Index CSV
    Output:
        Page CSV
    '''
    with open(file, 'r') as rf:
        reader = csv.reader(rf)

        base_name = os.path.basename(file)
        file_path = os.path.join(path, base_name)

        with open(file_path, 'w') as wf:
            writer = csv.writer(wf, delimiter = ',')

            for line in reader:
                url = line[-1]
                page_data = (parseFormPage(url))
                writer.writerow(page_data)

                time.sleep(3 + random.random() * 3)
```

```
# Create a new directory to save new CSV files
page_dir = './page'
if not os.path.isdir(page_dir):
    os.makedirs(page_dir)
os.path.isdir(page_dir)
```

```
for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        writeFormPage(filename, page_dir)
        time.sleep(3 + random.random() * 3)
```

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3a8a501dd2e9> in <module>
      1 for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
      2     if filename.endswith('.csv'):
----> 3         writeFormPage(filename, page_dir)
      4         time.sleep(3 + random.random() * 3)

<ipython-input-22-0fc6fceffe13> in writeFormPage(file, path)
      7         Page CSV
      8     '''
----> 9     with open(file, 'r') as rf:
     10         reader = csv.reader(rf)
     11 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2007Q2.csv'
```

The fact that the error names a file that I haven't specifically named, makes me wonder why it is saying the file is not found. The file mentioned is the first file in the directory that I would like to iterate over.
The pre-defined function in the first block of code is sound, I have tested this with a single csv file. I am just struggling with the loop. I am a beginner, and these loops seem to be my nemesis to be honest, they've caused me hours of headaches!
If anyone could help, I would be very grateful.

Comment: "listdir" only returns filenames without path but "open" uses the current working directory then. Build a full path with "os.path.join" or "pathlib".

Comment: you need `fullpath = os.path.join(indx_dir, filename)`

Comment: @furas Thank you both for your reply. Where would that argument need to go? I understand the concept, I think, but not enough to know which part it would it would relate to. I've tried adding in the `fullpath` code into a few places in the final block of code, but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: you have to send `fullpath` to `writeFormPage(fullpath, ...)` so you have to create it before line with `writeFormPage`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to furas for the help. The solution to this problem is to edit the last block of code to read as

```
for filename in os.listdir(indx_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        fullpath = os.path.join(indx_dir, filename)
        writeFormPage(fullpath, page_dir)
```